# mutable dictionary immutable in F#

Tags: dictionary, f#

I have code that declares a mutable dictionary but I will get an error when I try to change an element.

The code:

```
   let layers =
        seq {
            if recipes.ContainsKey(PositionSide.Short) then yield! buildLayerSide recipes.[PositionSide.Short]
            if recipes.ContainsKey(PositionSide.Long)  then yield! buildLayerSide recipes.[PositionSide.Long]
        }
        |> Seq.map (fun l -> l.Id, l)
        |> dict
```

this creates an `IDictionary`. I understand that the object itself is immutable but the contents of the dictionary should be mutable.

When I change the code by explicitly initializing the dictionary then it becomes mutable:

```
   let layers =
        let a =
            seq {
                if recipes.ContainsKey(PositionSide.Short) then yield! buildLayerSide recipes.[PositionSide.Short]
                if recipes.ContainsKey(PositionSide.Long)  then yield! buildLayerSide recipes.[PositionSide.Long]
            }
            |> Seq.map (fun l -> l.Id, l)
            |> dict
    let x = Dictionary<string, Layer>()
    a
    |> Seq.iter (fun kvp -> x.[kvp.Key] <- kvp.Value)

    x
```

Why is that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`IDictionary` is an *interface*, not a class. This interface may have multiple different implementations. You can even make one yourself.

`Dictionary` is indeed one of these implementations. It supports the full functionality of the interface.

But that's not the implementation that the `dict` function returns. Let's try this:

```
> let d = dict [(1,2)]
> d.GetType().FullName
"Microsoft.FSharp.Core.ExtraTopLevelOperators+DictImpl`3[...
```

Turns out the implementation that the `dict` function returns is `Microsoft.FSharp.Core.ExtraTopLevelOperators.DictImpl` - a class named `DictImpl` defined deep in the innards of the F# standard library.

And it just so happens that certain methods on that interface throw a `NotSupportedException`:

```
> d.Add(4,5)
System.NotSupportedException: This value cannot be mutated
```

That's by design. It's done this way on purpose, to support "immutability by default".

If you really want to have a mutable version, you can create a copy by using one of `Dictionary`'s constructors:

```
> let m = Dictionary(d)
> m.Add(4,5)  // Works now
```

---

The difference between `Map` and `Dictionary` is the implementation, which then implies memory and runtime characteristics.

`Dictionary` is a hashtable. It offers constant-time insertion and retrieval, but to pay for that it relies on consistent hashing of its keys and its updates are *destructive*, which also comes with thread-unsafety.

`Map` is implemented as a tree. It offers logarithmic insertion and retrieval, but in return has the benefits of a [*persistent data structure*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistent_data_structure). Also, it requires keys to be comparable. Try this:

```
> type Foo() = class end
> let m = Map [(Foo(), "bar")]
error FS0001: The type 'Foo' does not support the 'comparison' constraint
```

Comparing keys is essential for building a tree.

Comment: that clarifies it all; this was unclear for very long. So F# has two immutable dictionaries (Dictionary and Map) and the mutable BCL one.. also called Dictionary, but a totally different one. That opens an additional question: why can I do: xx |> dict but not xx |> Dictionary, while I can do xx |> Map, but xx |> map doesn't exist?  also, does "Dictionary" change meaning (F# vs. BCL) when I open System.Collections.Generic since the name is the same?

Comment: You're probably confusing `Dictionary` and `IDictionary`

Comment: I understand they all fall under the IDictionary interface, but if I instantiate a Dictionary, wouldn't the keywork Dictionary point to the BCL type, instead of the F# type, if I include System.Collections.Generic?

Comment: It's not a keyword, it's an identifier, but yes, it does identify a BCL class. The F# standard library, however, does not expose such identifier.

Answer (score 2):

The difference is that `dict` is a read-only dictionary with some mutating methods that throw an exception (which is a disadvantage of that type), whereas the map is an immutable collection that uses functions from the `Map` module as well as methods to modify elements of the map and return a copy. There is a good explanation of this in Lesson 17 of the book [Get Programming with F#](https://livebook.manning.com/book/get-programming-with-f-sharp/chapter-17/1).

Also, for the `dict`, "Retrieving a value by using its key is very fast, close to O(1), because the Dictionary class is implemented as a hash table." from [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-5.0); whereas the `map` is based on a binary tree, so retrieving a value by using its key has O(log(N)) complexity. See [Collection Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/fsharp-collection-types#table-of-functions). This also means that the keys in a `map` are ordered; whereas in a `dict`, they are unordered.

For many use cases, the difference in performance would be negligible, so the default choice for Functional Programming style should be the `map`, since its programming interface is similar in style to the other F# collections like `list` and `seq`.

Answer (score 0):

`dict` is a helper method to create an `iDictionary`, this dictionary is immutable (so you need to supply the contents during the creation of the object). It is actually a read-only dictionary so no surprise that you cannot modify its contents. In your second example you explicitly create a `Dictionary` which is a mutable dictionary. Since Dictionary can take a iDictionary you could just pass in your iDictionary to it.

Comment: I thought the Map was the immutable dictionary of F#?

Comment: what would be the difference then between |> dict or |> Map at the end of the creation if they both make an immutable dictionary